# Scrape table content with dropdown list with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to **scrape** ALL search results from https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/playersearch?POSITION=RB&print_rows=9999 for all the players of ALL positions.
[image]

I have achieved to get all RB players with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/playersearch?POSITION=RB&print_rows=9999')
html = html_text.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
player_table = soup.find('table', class_='data')

for tr in all_player_table.find_all('tr', class_=['row1','row2']):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print(("Player:%s , Position:%s , Team: %s") % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

I am now facing to deal with scraping players in other positions from the dropdown list. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is pretty simple: You can scrape all the positions, modify the URL and search for all players. In code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = "https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/playersearch"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(main_url).text, "html.parser")

# Scrape all positions
positions = [o["value"] for o in soup.find("select", {'name' : "POSITION"}).find_all("option")]

for position in positions:
    url = f"{main_url}?POSITION={position}&print_rows=9999"
    # Find all players
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    for tr in soup.find("table", class_="data").find_all("tr", class_=["row1", "row2"]):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        print(("Player: %s , Position: %s , Team: %s") % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

Comment: That was awesome! I have a follow-up question (I probably should ask as a separate question), each player has a subsequential page (tds[0]) listing player info such as height/weight, age, hometown, etc. Is it possible to scrap those info?

Comment: @Meruemu Sure, you could extract the player url by `tds[0].a["href"]`, create a new soup object and scrape the new website. All the player info are inside a `div`-tag with css-classes `featureComponent stdPad mBottom10`. Feel free to ask a separate question in case you need help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have my own try first.